# Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I add to my sources.list file this repository:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

I need that to install php7.0 on my raspberry pi, after I execute command in terminal:

```
_ apt-get install -t stretch mysql-server mysql-client php7.0-mysql -y
```

now always when I try to install any package I got many messages like this:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.*?)(\\)?\${ <-- HERE ([^{}]+)}(.*)$/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 72.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 30.
```

of course I install them properly but message looks weird.

Anyone could tell me what it means and how to solve it?

Comment: See also: [Saving command output to a variable in bash results in "Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated"](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/322873)

Answer (score 5):

it's reported upstream and upstream reports it being fixed in 2015:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=786705

however i still see that error on my debian 8.8 with debconf-1.5.56.all installed, the machine was installed in 2016.

to fix this, i ran `apt-get install debconf`

you may run `apt-get dist-upgrade` to update all packages in system, but beware it may update to 8.8 -> 9.0

Answer (score 4):

It's a warning. The folks who maintain that code will need to escape the left braces, e.g. change `{` in the regular expression to `\{`. Reporting this to the folks to maintain that code may help, as it's a trivial fix.

Comment: Can you tell me which file should I edit? Or if I'm wrong, they should edit file on repo?

Comment: Any updates on reporting this?

Comment: The error warning tells you in which file and line you have to search

Answer (score 3):

you simply have to open the file that is mentioned within the warning

m/^(.*?)(\)?\${ <-- HERE ([^{}]+)}(.*)$/ at **/usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm** line 72.

go to the mentioned **line 72** and add a backslash in front of the left brace where the warning points to with **<-- HERE**